# How to use @media to change width in prop styled components

Tags: css, reactjs

I am not sure if what they called but I have a component which takes its style as an object with its props.

```
const PricingSection = ({
    secDesc,
}) => {

    return (
        <Text
            {...secDesc}
            content={intl.formatMessage({ id: 'packages.description' })}
        />
    );
};


PricingSection.propTypes = {
    secDesc: PropTypes.object
};

PricingSection.defaultProps = {
    secDesc: {
        width: '50%',
        m: 'auto',
        textAlign: 'center',
        pt: '20px',
        color: '#6a7a8d',
        lineHeight: '1.5rem',
    },
}
```

I want to apply different `witdh` for mobile devices. I know how to use `@media` tag in css but I dont know where to write `@media` in this component or how achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing style object, it would be better if you apply a class to the component for easy maintenance. It'll also solve your problem for `width` for different size devices as you can add media query for the class in its css file.

Another suggestion would be to use [`styled-components`](https://jsramblings.com/how-to-use-media-queries-with-styled-components/). They provide great support for adding media queries inside the component file.

Refer:[styled-components](https://styled-components.com/docs)

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'react-device-detect' and pass the different width from parent component like this:

```
enter code here
import isMobile from 'react-device-detect'
secDesc: {
   width: isMobile ? '50%' : 'your value',
   m: 'auto',
   textAlign: 'center',
   pt: '20px',
   color: '#6a7a8d',
   lineHeight: '1.5rem',
 }
 < PricingSection 
    secDesc={secDesc}
  />
```